# Find the equation of two straight lines tangent

Tags: calculus

I need to find the equation of two straight lines that are tangent to $ \frac{1}{x} $ now I've calculated the slope to be $ \frac{1}{-x^2} $ and I know that my lines must be of the form $y=-2x + m $ but I'm not sure how I go about isolating m.

A nudge is needed.

Comment: $m$ is "how high" your tangent is. You can find it by substituting the points of the tangent $(x,y) = (x, \dfrac1x)$

Comment: Ah, of course. Why don't you put that in an answer and I will accept as best answer. Your comment enabled me to complete my problem.

Comment: There are many pairs of parallel lines tangent to your given function. I could come up with $y=-x+2$ with $y=-x-2$ for example. THE equation ,as the poster wants, would be $(y+x)^2=4$